# Unable to call a method of super class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

- This is a simple demo of inheritance. Here I am unable to call the
  super class method.
- I am trying to implement method overriding here.

.

```
class supers {
    int x, y;

    supers(int a, int b) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }

    final void volume() {
        System.out.println("area is " + x * y);
    }
}

class sub extends supers {
    int z;

    sub(int a, int b, int c) {
        super(a, b);
        z = c;
    }

    void volume() {
        System.out.println("volume is " + x * y * z);
    }
}

class m{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        supers obj = new sub(1, 2, 3);
        obj.volume();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add some info .

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: I do see a problem though: the method `volume` is the base class is defined `final` and can therefore not be overridden by a derived class.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you have declared the `volume()` as `final` in the `supers` class.  That means that overriding it in a child class is forbidden by the compiler.

The methods *may* also need to be declared as `public`.  It depends on whether the classes are in the same (named) package<sup>1</sup>.   (If they are, the methods can remain as package private.  If not, then the methods, constructors and / or the classes themselves may need to be `public`.)

---

Finally, you need to learn the Java naming conventions.  A class name should *always* start with an uppercase letter.

---

<sup>1 - This is not clear from the snippets.  They appear to show a single file with no `package` declaration.  But that would not compile ... because a source file containing classes in the "default" package needs one of the classes to be `public`.   Referencing a package-private class in the "default" package is difficult.  Basically, using the "default" package is a  bad idea for practical applications.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Write `void volume()` instead of `final void volume`

Don't use `final` keyword. Your program should look like:

```
import java.util.*;

class Supers {
    int x,y; 
    Supers(int a,int b) {
    x = a;
    y = b;
} 
void volume() {
    System.out.println("area is "+ x*y); 
 } 
} 
  class Sub extends Supers {
  int z; 
  Sub(int a,int b,int c) { 
  super(a,b); 
  z = c;
} 
  void volume() { 
  super.volume(); // Call volume() method of Supers class
  System.out.println("volume is "+ x*y*z); 
 }  
}

class M {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
   Sub obj = new Sub(1,2,3);
   obj.volume(); 
 } 
}
```

Use `final` if you wish to prevent the sub classes from overriding the members of the super class.

In above program, we have method `volume()` with same name and same parameter in sub class as well as in parent class. So `volume()` method, while we are inheriting the parent class, will be overridden in sub class. And that's why the line `System.out.println("area is "+ x*y);` can't be printed because `volume()` method of sub class will override the method. So the line `System.out.println("volume is "+ x*y*z);` will be executed.

**To call volume method of Supers class, most effective way is to use `super.volume()` in volume() method of sub class as shown in above code.**

Output:

`area is 2
volume is 6`

Or we can create an object in main method. Then this will look like this:

```
class M {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
   Supers obj1 = new Supers(2,4);
   obj1.volume();
   Sub obj = new Sub(1,2,3);
   obj.volume(); 
  } 
}
```

Or instead of accessing volume() method of Super class, we can just add `System.out.println("area is "+ x*y);` in volume() method of sub class.

```
void volume() { 
   System.out.println("area is "+ x*y); 
   System.out.println("volume is "+ x*y*z); 
}
```

Comment: how to call the volume() method of supers class in this code.

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly as the method is `final` it cannot be overridden in the derived class. So final keyword must be removed.
- And secondly you can use the super keyword to call the base class method.
- The derived class can be modified as follows by `super.method_name();`:

  ```
  class sub extends supers {

      int z;

      sub(int a, int b, int c) {
          super(a, b);
          z = c;
      }

      void volume() {
          super.volume();
          System.out.println("volume is " + x * y * z);
      }

  }
  ```

Comment: if i remove the final keyword from the supers class method then is it possible to call the method by using the sub class object. without using the super.volume();.

Comment: Yes, but the method name of the super class must be changed as if method name is same i.e. method overriding, then each time sub class method will be referred. Sources: [super keyword](https://www.javatpoint.com/super-keyword), [method overriding](https://www.javatpoint.com/method-overriding-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Super {

    final void inherit() {
    // the method states that you cannot inherit this method to you sub-class
    }
}

class SubClass extends Super {

    //This is not allowed as you cannot inherit and get the compile time exception to remove final keyword.

    /*void inherit() {

    }*/
}
```

hence to call volume method of super class, you need to remove the final keyword from the volume method of super class.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the final keyword as it stops you from overriding.
Also,  use the name of class after super keyword.